# Visualising the contents of three variables

Tags: data-visualization, python, stata

Suppose i have the following two variables

```
 var1            var2

     0            -869        
  5000            3593        
 10000            8055        
 15000           12517        
 20000           16979        
 25000           21441        
 30000           25903     
 35000           30365        
 40000           34827        
 45000           39289        
 50000           43751        
 55000           48213        
 60000           52676        
 65000           57138        
 70000           61600        
 75000           66062        
 80000           70524        
 85000           74986        
 90000           79448        
 95000           83910        
100000           88372
```

It is easy to visualize the contents of these two variables using a line chart.

But what happens if i have three variables, with the third variable being the **composite** of the other two? That is the values of var3 are generated based on the values of var1 and var2?

```
  var1     var2        var3

     0     5000        -869        
  5000    10000        3593        
 10000    15000        8055        
 15000    20000       12517        
 20000    25000       16979        
 25000    30000       21441        
 30000    35000       25903     
 35000    40000       30365        
 40000    45000       34827        
 45000    50000       39289        
 50000    55000       43751        
 55000    60000       48213        
 60000    65000       52676        
 65000    70000       57138        
 70000    75000       61600        
 75000    80000       66062        
 80000    85000       70524        
 85000    90000       74986        
 90000    95000       79448        
 95000   100000       83910        
100000   105000       88372
```

How can i visualize all three variables at the same time?

Comment: What are var1, 2 and 3? In your example, they look kind of odd.

Comment: You might like this 
 https://github.com/ketansahils/LinearLogisticRegressionIntuition/blob/master/LinearRegression.ipynb . Scroll down to the bottom of the page for 3D visualization along with the code.

Comment: This looks very interesting @ketan, will  definitely have a look at it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data points lie on a 1d curve (a line in this case), so they're easy to plot in 3d:

[image]

In general, the relationship between variables may not be so straightforward. You can always plot the raw points in 3d. For example:

[image]

If the data lie on a 2d surface (as in this example), the surface can be interpolated and plotted in 3d:

[image]

or as a heat map, where Z is represented by color:

[image]

or as a contour plot, where the lines represent contours with equal Z values (like a topographic map):

[image]

If the data form a dense 3d cloud rather than a 1d curve or 2d surface, you can construct a 3d [volume plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_rendering). Depending on the data, this may not be as straightforward to visualize. It may require some form of simplification, like cutting away part of the volume to visualize the interior, examining 2d slices of the volume, or plotting [isosurfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosurface) (a 3d analog of a contour plot). More examples [here](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/examples.html).

Comment: Thank you.  Did you draw these graphs in Python? Also, could you recommend some references that explain all this in a bit more detail?

Comment: I used matlab for these plots. The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/2-and-3d-plots.html) is a good reference. For Python, the standard plotting library is [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/). The mplot3d toolkit extends it for 3d plotting. You can check out their documentation and tutorials. Mayavi (link above) is a Python library for fancier 3d plotting. Otherwise, searching for 'data visualization tutorial' would probably turn up a lot of results.

Comment: Can i also use a common line chart but with two x-axes and a y-axis to draw my data in this case? The 3d aspect seems to complicate things.

Comment: Yes, you could do that in this case

Comment: Could you please provide some guidance on how to interpret the heat map and contour plots? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Heat map: Say you're looking straight down at a 3d surface (bird's eye view). You can see the x and y axes. The height (z) of the surface at each (x,y) coordinate is represented as the color. The color bar to the right of the plot shows how different heights are colored. I plotted the surface plot above the heat map with the same colors, so you can directly compare them (imagine rotating the surface plot to look straight down at it).

Comment: The contour plot has the same point of view. It has lines added to show the contours. Each contour line is a path through x and y where the height doesn't change. Imagine them as trails on the side of mountain where the elevation is constant. The elevations are chosen at even intervals, so the slope is steeper where the contour lines are closer together.

Comment: Thank you. But what does each colour / contour line mean? Eg in your example, if x is weight, y is height and z daily consumption of meat what does the heat map and contour plot tell us about their relationship?

Comment: In that example, the x and y axes of the plots are possible values of weight and height, and color represents meat consumption for each of them. If height and weight change by moving along a contour line, meat consumption remains fixed. These plots tell you the same things as the 3d surface plot, it's just easier to see exactly what the x and y values are.

Answer (score 2):

In Stata, you can try:

```
twoway contour var3 var2 var1, interp(none)

surface var1 var2 var3, nowire
graph3d var1 var2 var3, cuboid xang(45) yang(45) innergrid colorscheme(bcgyr) blv xlab(var1) ylab(var2) zlab(var3)
```

You may need to install the last two with `ssc install command`.

This will require some fiddling to make interpretable, but they are similar to the MATLAB/Python graphs in the other post.